Is a database necessary for a hardcoded quiz game or would just a list be enough
This is just sample code of my current configuration, I have around 750 levels right now, max i would have is a 1000.
class GameLevel {
  final int number;
  final String question;
  final int answer;
  final String? image;
  final int difficulty;
  final String hint;
  final String solution;

  const GameLevel({
    required this.number,
    required this.question,
    required this.answer,
    this.image,
    required this.difficulty,
    required this.hint,
    required this.solution,
  });
}

const List<GameLevel> gameLevels = [
  GameLevel(
    number: 1,
    question: 'whats 1 + 2',
    answer: 3,
    difficulty: 4,
    hint: '+2',
    solution: '3',
  ),
  GameLevel(
    number: 2,
    question: 'whats 3 + 7',
    answer: 10,
    difficulty: 4,
    hint: 'x3',
    solution: '3 + 7 = 10',
  ),

Is it good enough to just store all the levels in the levels.dart file, or do i need to use a database. Best option i have found is sqflite. I have built the apk with all levels just saved in this dart file and the game runs fine. I want to know if it ll be any slower on older devices or while going to level 750  for example. These levels are to be hardcoded in the game and offline only. Also this is my first flutter project. Any and all advice are welcome.

It is not necessary to use a database for your hard-coded data in order for your app to work. If you have a list, that can serve the purpose just fine. Looping 1000 items is not a huge cost on modern devices, but out of principle I strongly advise you to make sure that your code is effective.
If you want to store your game levels in a list, then you should always keep track of the current item index as well as the current GameLevel object, so you will not need to search for it by position.
Yet, I wonder why you decided to use a List rather than an array of GameLevel objects. If you had an array instead of a list, then the references of the GameLevel object would be stored in a quickly traceable memory section instead of allocated list items being scattered across memory and having to do a loop in order to find the n'th element (under the hood, you are not doing this yourself).
Further problems you will need to consider is whether you will need to update this list of yours and whether you want to release a new apk whenever there are changes upon game levels. Wouldn't it make more sense to have a storage outside your apk which you could update without needing to release a new version each time?
This does not necessarily mean that you have a database, you could achieve functionally the same with a file too that your app would load upon initialization.
Yet, using a database is very elegant, albeit not necessary. Because if you have a database, then you can script the changes rather than having to override files each time and it becomes much easier to maintain your game level data. However, you can postpone all these improvements to later versions, sooner or later you will feel the miss of proper data handling and will be able to decide for yourself what improvements you will want and to what extent.
